# Nautilus has a double title bar on ubuntu unity 22.04. Is there any config to hide the additional title bar?

Tags: unity, nautilus

Nautilus has a double title bar on ubuntu unity 22.04. Is there any config to hide the additional title bar?

[image: nautilus screenshot]

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Ubuntu Unity is a respin and not an official flavor of Ubuntu - it has its own forum/support venues including telegram group*

Comment: @guiverc judging the screenshot, this could be official Ubuntu 22.04 with Unity installed. I think the respin changed to Nemo file manager (and uses some apps with traditional menus from Mate) to avoid issues with CSD. But then, the question indeed suggests that this is the respin...

Comment: Issue confirmed on official Ubuntu 22.04 with Unity installed. Nautilus has a double header.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple things you could try:

Restart Nautilus for any unwanted processes using `nautilus -q` 
This restarts the Nautilus file manager and it can be a solution to your problem.

Check that Unity is one and ONLY window manager and that there is no other third-party window manager. Check your Unity settings and make sure they're the default settings. If not, reset them using the command line using `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/nautilus/`  and restart Nautilus.

Also, GNOME has replaced Unity as default desktop environment so if Unity isn't compatible with Ubuntu 22.04 you could try the default GNOME desktop or use another (like KDE Plasma). Try updating your system too.